# How to Redirect 404 page to custom error page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Actually I am trying to redirect all the 404 page to 404.php using .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?localhost.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|css|js|png)$ - [F]

#for 404 page
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . 404.php [L]
```

my file structure is like
[structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5Ad.png)

so what happens it works fine for the url like localhost/srmures/hr/fgh
[errorpageone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sj5Ad.png)

But when I change url like localhost/srmures/hr/fgh/gdj then it doesn't recognize the css file and add the html file into it..
[errorpagetwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSgUZ.png)

So how to solve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add `*` after the dot in `RewriteRule` ? Or use ^ instead of the dot ?

Comment: did you try `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php`

Comment: @Ayush Srivastava what do you meant by  it doesn't recognize the css file and add the html file into it.? please explain ?

Comment: @mohammed when I inspect the page and see the css file then instead of css rule it gives the HTML code in css file as I give in the screenshot please see in the question